# Android - play sound on button click - Null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play a sound file on the click of a button. The sound is just 1 sec long. It plays well the first few times I click the button, but after a while it gives a `NullPointerException`. Here's the code:

```
button[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {        
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(Test.this, R.raw.mysound);   
        mp.start();
    }
});
```

And here's the exception:

```
07-29 23:07:27.690: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10542): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-29 23:07:27.710: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10542): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-29 23:07:27.710: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10542):     at com.example.mypackage.Test$3.onClick(Test.java:270)
```

Comment: not sure if it helps, but maybe try a mp.reset() on completion?

Comment: If you want to have the resources managed automatically, so that you can call `MusicManager.getInstance().play(this, R.raw.my_sound);` etc., this library might be for you: https://github.com/delight-im/Android-Audio

Answer (score 101):

Thanks you for your answers! Appreciate it!

Here's how I finally managed to get it work:

```
            button[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Test.this, R.raw.mysound);
                    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            mp.release();
                        }

                    });   
                    mp.start();
                }

            });
```

Comment: seems like perhaps the .setOnCompletionListener should come before the .start not after (?)

Comment: changed the order of the calls

Comment: this should be in the developper.android's tutorial

Comment: Simple and working like a charm. Exactly what I need for my case. Although for short sounds like 1 sec I might go for the SoundPool instead of MediaPlayer. Thx anyways!

Answer (score 24):

You can also try:

```
final soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
final sound = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.mysound, 1);

button[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
     public void onClick(View view)
     {       
         soundPool.play(sound, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);
     }
});
```

Comment: Seems like this is the better way to do it when playing a repetitive, short sound on button click (rather than creating/destroying a media player each time). Don't forget to do a `soundPool.release();` in your `onDestroy` (or wherever you're cleaning up the Activity) though.

Comment: @Alconja In my experience there isn't any guarantee onDestroy will actually be called (i.e. the Android task killer usually kills my app with no warning).

Comment: @Michael whenever the app is killed this way, there's usually no need to deallocate resources as your whole process gets terminated and everything it had open and allocated is closed and deallocated automatically by the system.

Answer (score 4):

It might solve your problem,

```
button[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {     
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(Test.this, R.raw.mysound);   
                 mp.start();
        }.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: Still works fine for the first few clicks, and then gives a null pointer exception, particularly when I click buttons quickly in succession.

Comment: can you try,
1) putting check before starting. i mean check if player is in playing stage then don't execute this statement

mp = MediaPlayer.create(Test.this, R.raw.mysound);   
mp.start();

or
2) make mp as local variable

Answer (score 1):

You should catch Exception.

try this code:

```
     try{
         MediaPlayer mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(contextTop, R.raw.<your sound>);
         mplayer.start();
     }catch(Exception e){
         Log.d("<your TAG here>" , "error: " + e);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If still your issue not solved then try this as it help me.

```
    public void playSound(int resources){
        try{
            boolean mStartPlaying = true;
            MediaPlayer  mPlayer=null;
            if (mStartPlaying==true){
                mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://YOUR_PACKAGENAME/" + resources);
                mPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),uri);
                mPlayer.prepare();
                mPlayer.start();
            } 
            else{
                mPlayer.release();
                mPlayer = null;
            }
            mStartPlaying = !mStartPlaying;
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }

//       MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(SpyMainActivity.this, resources);
//       mp.start();

    }
```

Enjoy. :)