# Is there any predefined sound on android?

Tags: android, audio

I'm wondering, if there is any predefined sounds in Android that I can use in my application.

I was trying to use a class called [SoundManager](http://www.droidnova.com/creating-sound-effects-in-android-part-1,570.html) which is build specifically for sound playing in an efficient way.

I realized that what I need is **much much smaller** than this class. I need a click sound when the button is clicked and a navigation sound when the user navigate through a menu or a set of buttons.

I guess there is something in the android API fit to my purpose but I could not find it.
any help please in finding it and hoe to use it?

Comment: Whats wrong with SoundManager?

Comment: Very good Except that it is MUCH bigger than what I need !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look into the [View.playSoundEffect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#playSoundEffect%28int%29) api. This method accepts a [SoundEffectConstants](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SoundEffectConstants.html#CLICK) value where, among others, a `CLICK` constant is available.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. I knew there is something like this but I could not find it. I didn't test it but I hope it will work with me. Thanks @Peter :)

Comment: @2rk - that's great. Perhaps you could share your findings here when you get it to work? Good luck!

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out another problem. Then, I will update this. This method won't work unless the `phone's Audible Selection` is _enabled_. You may can help here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6555410/543711)

Answer (score 0):

Using the MediaPlayer it's really simple, see for instance this SO thread:
[Android - play sound on button click - Null pointer exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369068/android-play-sound-on-button-click-null-pointer-exception)

Comment: I am aware of media player. But I need something very light. I have no media to play. It is just **Simple Click**. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean light? You only need like 5 lines of code and a 1 kilobyte sound :)

Comment: I understand @2rk, he wants to know if there is a built-in resource in the platform that can be used, like a simple audio notification.

Comment: That is exactly what I want @Peter