# Problem with View.playSoundEffect?

Tags: android, view, playsound

I'm trying to play a soundEffect (using `View.playSoundEffec()` method) when a button is focused.

The problem is the effects will never be played unless the target phone's Audible Selection is enabled
( It can be enabled from: `Settings => Sounds & display => Audible Selection` )

What I want is, when the Audible selection isn't enabled, I want to enable it in a programmatic way. Is this possible ?