# WAV file MediaPlayer

Tags: android

I'm trying to play a WAV file from the SD card. It works on some phones (Nexus S, Nexus One etc.) but not in Xperia Mini series.

Code:

```
// On some phones, this line works, but on Xperia Mini 
// series phones MediaPlayer.create()
// returns null from this line below.
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)));
```

[The LogCat error message can be found here](http://pastebin.com/wSPvHHqp).

Any ideas? It certainly works on some phones, but other phones just reject the wav file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be the same issue (and solution) as this one:
[Android - play sound on button click - Null pointer exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369068/android-play-sound-on-button-click-null-pointer-exception)

Comment: The issue is a little bit different. I cannot even call `mp.start()` on the `MediaPlayer` object and when I do, it gives me a NPE.

Comment: Gah! Stupid me! My own recorded wav file was in the wrong format. Thanks for contributing!